# Converting data format

Tags: r, dataset, rstudio, data-formats

I'm trying to use the recent COVID-19 data from the site of Italian Civil Protection, but they use a rather complicated time format that I'm finding troublesome as a novice to plot as data in a graph.
This is how the data is presented:

```
[1] 2020-02-24T18:00:00 2020-02-25T18:00:00 2020-02-26T18:00:00 2020-02-27T18:00:00 2020-02-28T18:00:00 2020-02-29T18:00:00
```

and I would like to use the format as DD-MM, without the time and the year.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `as.Date`, see below.

```r
dates.text <- c("2020-02-24T18:00:00", "2020-02-25T18:00:00", "2020-02-26T18:00:00",
                "2020-02-27T18:00:00", "2020-02-28T18:00:00", "2020-02-29T18:00:00")
dates.text
# [1] "2020-02-24T18:00:00" "2020-02-25T18:00:00" "2020-02-26T18:00:00" "2020-02-27T18:00:00"
# [5] "2020-02-28T18:00:00" "2020-02-29T18:00:00"

dates.dates <- as.Date(dates.text)
dates.dates
# [1] "2020-02-24" "2020-02-25" "2020-02-26" "2020-02-27" "2020-02-28" "2020-02-29"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Have a nice day and stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split the string :

```
x = "2020-02-24T18:00:00 2020-02-25T18:00:00 2020-02-26T18:00:00"

x = strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]]

[1] "2020-02-24T18:00:00" "2020-02-25T18:00:00" "2020-02-26T18:00:00"
```

Then you can just the result as dates :

```
x = as.Date(x)
[1] "2020-02-24" "2020-02-25" "2020-02-26"
```